# How I can get function local variables under debugging script in NLua?

Tags: c#, debugging, local-variables, nlua

When I debug lua-script, using NLua, and when I reach DoSomething() function call (line with return statement), how I can get list of function local variables (int1, int2, int3 and str1), and get their values? Is there possible, or I can see only global variables?

```
function DoSomething()
    int1 = 10
    int2 = 20
    int3 = 30
    str1 = "bla bla bla"

    return nil
end

result = DoSomething()
```